# Trying to set cookies but get a TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, post, cookies, python-requests, mechanize

I have python code that looks like this

```html
from shlex import split
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import mechanize
import urllib
with open("Myaccount.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split(':')
        print parts[0]
        br = mechanize.Browser()
        br.set_handle_robots(False)
        br.addheaders = [("User-agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36")]
        sign_in = br.open("https://website.com/login/")
        br.select_form(nr = 0)
        br["username"] = parts[0] 
        br["password"] = parts[1]   
        logged_in = br.submit()   
        logincheck = logged_in.read()
        print "logincheck"
        cookies = br._ua_handlers['_cookies'].cookiejar
        payload = {'action':'info',
                   'action':'info',
                   'api_key':'something'
                   }

        with open("cookie.txt", "w") as text_file:
            text_file.write("%s" % cookies)
            payload = {'action':'info',
                   'action':'info',
                   'api_key':'something'
                   }
            text_file.close()

        with open("cookie.txt", "r") as text_file:
            for line in text_file:
                yup = line
                payload = {'action':'info',
                   'action':'info',
                   'api_key':'something'
                   }
                print yup
                r = requests.post("https://website.com",data = payload, cookies =yup)
```

But i keep getting the error "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str" no matter what i do, it only seems to go away when remove "cookie" entirely from my post request at the bottom, any help would be appreciated

here's what the traceback error looks like

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/my name/Desktop/program.py", line 43, in <module>
    r = requests.post("https://website.com",data = payload, cookies = cookies)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\requests\api.py", line 108, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\requests\api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\requests\sessions.py", line 450, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\requests\sessions.py", line 358, in prepare_request
    cookies = cookiejar_from_dict(cookies)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\requests\cookies.py", line 439, in cookiejar_from_dict
    cookiejar.set_cookie(create_cookie(name, cookie_dict[name]))
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask].  `cookie_dict[name])` - did you happen to inspect/print `cookie_dict` and `name`? is `name` a string or an integer? You could [handle the exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and print those variables in the except suite.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean, im very new to python and had to learn as i wrote this

Comment: @wwii can you show me how to fix my code?

Comment: Maybe `yup` is supposed to be a dictionary?

Comment: From the [`requests` source](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/api/#request) : `:param cookies: (optional) Dict or CookieJar object to send with the :class:`Request`.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In requests, when you try [to send cookies](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies) in the request, `cookies` kwarg should be a dictionary. Instead what you have tried to send is a string. Change it to a dictionary of what you're trying to send as cookies.

**Edit**: I see you're trying to save the cookies to a file and then using it for a later request. What is happening here is that you're saving the cookiejar object as it is. Which doesn't help when you try to retrieve it. Instead what you should do is to pickle the object and save it. Python requests framework provide a method to convert the cookiejar object to dictionary [`requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar)

The line

```
cookies = br._ua_handlers['_cookies'].cookiejar
payload = {'action':'info',
               'action':'info',
               'api_key':'something'
               }

with open("cookie.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write("%s" % cookies)
    payload = {'action':'info',
               'action':'info',
               'api_key':'something'
               }
    text_file.close()
```

should be changed to

```
import requests, pickle
with open('cookie.txt', 'w') as text_file:
    pickle.dump(requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(br._ua_handlers['_cookies'].cookiejar), text_file)
```

And then when you fetch the cookies, it should be

```
with open('cookie.txt', 'r') as text_file:
    yup = requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict(pickle.load(text_file))
```

Comment: how do i turn something into a "dictionary" , im trying to skip the saving to a file all together

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, python requests framework provide a method to convert the cookiejar object to dictionary `requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar`